# code is working in localhost but it is not working in hostgator server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

`dropdown` box based on values should be display in text fields,

present code is working in localhost but in not working on hostgator server

example country based on the state and state based on the district

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#state').on('change', function () {
                var stateID = $(this).val();
                if (stateID) {                   
                    $.ajax({                 
                        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/myform/ajax/' + stateID,
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",           
                        success: function (data) {        
                            console.log(data);
                            var title = [], metatags = [], decription = [];
                            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                                title.push(value.page_title);
                                metatags.push(value.page_metatags);
                                decription.push(value.page_decription);
                            });
                            $('input[name="city"]').val(title.join(','));
                            $('input[name="Metatags"]').val(metatags.join(','));
                            $('input[name="Description"]').val(decription.join(','));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**routes.php**

```
    $route['myform'] = 'welcome';
    $route['myform/ajax/(:any)'] = 'welcome/myformAjax/$1';
```

**welcome.php**

```
 public function update() {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data['state_fetch'] = $this->Question_Insertion_Model->all_Pages_Display();
    $this->load->view('update', $data);
    }
    public function myformAjax($id) {
    $this->db->select('c.*');
    $this->db->where("s.page_id", urldecode($id));
    $this->db->join('kas_all_pages s', 's.page_id = c.page_fk');
    $result = $this->db->get('kas_all_pages_tags c')->result();
    echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: what is the error pls details

Comment: stateID values not getting in ajax success function in hostgator server but in localhost code working fine

Comment: have u updated your base url in the server

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://demo/go_to_admin_panel/admin';

Comment: alert(stateID); in success function values are not printing...but in my local system printing values

Comment: go to console  see what is the error it shows

Comment: pls check your `console` and provide the error message

Comment: nothing displaying in console..in localhost getting values no errors

Comment: please check if you load jQuery correctly...

Comment: check in the Network tab then, click on the ajax request, see what HTTP status you get back, and what response, if any. If the status is "200 OK" then it's executing ok, anything else indicates a potential problem. Of course if it's "200 OK" and the Response tab of the request is empty, then simply it means your server found no data it could return. Did you populate your database with the correct data?

Comment: @ADyson i checked status os 200 in local system working fine

Comment: @ADyson getting error in network ::A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mysql.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:

Comment: We're not interested in the status in the local version, we need the status in the hostel version. Unless I misunderstood your slightly unclear comment? Anyway if the status is 200 in both versions, then go ahead and do as I suggested and check that the database in the hosted version is populated with any matching data. Didn't you do that yet?

Comment: Ah OK just seen latest comment...sounds like maybe MySQL library code for php is not installed properly on the host. Contact the hosting support if that's the case. Do any other queries work? Do you use the same database connection throughout your code?

Answer (score 1):

in index.php just add the below code

- NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
  */
  $_SERVER['CI_ENV']='production';